# async reducer with react-router seems to have multiple stores?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I have an async reducer structure. On any given page, I inject the page's reducer with:

```
export const injectReducer = (store, { key, reducer }) => {
  // store.asyncReducers already initialized to {}
  // makeRootReducer just returns combineReducers({...store.asyncReducers})

  store.asyncReducers[key] = reducer
  store.replaceReducer(makeRootReducer(store.asyncReducers))
}
```

I use `react-router 3` and the plain routes definitions on any given page. I use `require.ensure` for async handling of routes within `getComponent` of the plain route definition:

```
export default (store) => ({
  path : 'counter',
  getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {

      const Counter = require('./containers/Counter').default
      const reducer = require('./modules/counter').default

      injectReducer(store, { key: 'counter', reducer })

      cb(null, Counter)

    }, 'Counter')
  }
})
```

My problem is that if I use `dispatch` followed by `browserHistory.push`, I would expect that the state gets updated before going to the new page. What happens however, is that there appears to be 2 separate stores. For example, navigating between pages, the value of the counter from the previous page seems to be preserved despite it being on the same key. What is going on here???

Sample [repo](https://github.com/terencechow/react-redux-starter-kit) of my problem. You can `git clone`, `npm install`, `npm start` and go to `localhost:3000/counter`. If you click `Double (Async)` it doubles the counter and then goes to the `/otherPage`. If you then click `Half (Async)` it will bring you back to `/counter`. However the value of the counter is the value from `doubling`, not from `halving`. Also, importantly, pulling up `Redux DevTools` and navigating between the pages seems to show the counter change for ALL data before. Almost as if the entire store was replaced, yet the prior values are preserved.

What is going on here???

Answer (score 0):

After much investigation I have discovered that in development ReduxDevTools will recompute the entire state history on a new page. Inserting a new reducer where initialState is different on the new page results in 2 different results. There are not 2 stores or any caches, it is just redux dev tools recomputing the entire state history with different initialStates.

Hence in my scenario, dispatch was updating the state on my first page. Then browserHistory makes a push to go to the second page. The second page recomputes the entire state history. However the second page has a reducer that is missing the action handler for the first page. Hence when recomputing the entire state history, the state doesn't change from that last action.